# Are the JUnit @Rule and ExpectedException.none() thread-safe?

Tags: java, junit, thread-safety

I am writing a JUnit test and I want it to test that an exception is thrown so wrote the following the Java test class (this is not the actually JUnit test I wrote but one that illustrates the point I am trying to get across).

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testMethod1() {
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Parameter cannot be null");

    UtilClass.getSampleValue(null, new Object());
}

@Test
public void testMethod2() {
    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("Parameter cannot be null");

    UtilClass.getSampleValue(new Object(), null);
}

@Test
public void testMethod3() {
    final Object actual = UtilClass.getSampleValue(new Object(), new Object());
    assertNotNull(actual);
}
```

When I sent this for code review some wrote on the review that that using `@Rule` means that the test methods are not thread-safe and that in the future if we wanted to move to running the [test methods in parallel](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) it would not work because the test that did not expect exception would actually see an exception.  Is this true?  Is there a workaround for this?  I could not find any documentation on the web regarding this.

Comment: AFAIK, each `@Test` should be running within its own instance.

Comment: Does that mean that each `@Test` will have its own copy of the `@Rule`?

Comment: Yes, that field is an instance field, one per instance. And since each thread running a `@Test` has its own instance of the test class, they're all operating on different `ExpectedException` objects through their `thrown` fields.